# How can I change output from a Bash script while waiting on user input?

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I want to build a stopwatch in Bash, with a pause feature. It should display an incrementing counter, like [this one](https://github.com/coryfklein/sw) does, but pause it when I hit the "p" key.

How should I implement that? If I wait for user input with `read` I can't refresh the counter on the screen at the same time. Putting the `read` inside a loop, with a timeout, is my best plan so far, but it's non-trivial to use a timeout less than one second, which is what I would need here. (It's not supported by `read` or GNU `timeout`.) Interrupts would work, but I'd like to support arbitrary keys like "p" and "x".

Is there a reasonably simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Something with a background process to update the counter, and then kill that if you get user input?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are your limitations? Does it *need* to be done in bash? Sure it *can* be done in bash but it wourld probably not be as *reasonably simple* as in other languages.

Comment: @brunorey - My preference is to figure out how to do it in Bash, but I'd consider other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## Print to console while waiting for  user input

1. Write one function that creates the output (example with: `counter` or if you like  `spin`).
2. Write one function to read in user commands (`readCommand`)
3. Call both functions in a loop
4. Set timeouts so, that key presses are read soon enough. (`sleep .1` and `read -t.1`)

```
function readCommand(){
   lastCommand=$1
   read -t.1 -n1 c;
   if [ "$c" = "p" ]
   then
     printf "\n\r"; 
     return 0
   fi
   if [ "$c" = "g" ]
   then
     printf "\n\r"; 
     return 1
   fi
  return $lastCommand
}

function spin(){
    for i in / - \\ \| ;
        do 
            printf "\r$i"; 
            sleep .1;
        done
}

function countUp(){
    currentCount=$1
    return `expr $currentCount + 1`
}

function counter(){
    countUp $count
    count=$?
    printf "\r$count"
    sleep .1;
}

command=1
count=0
while : 
do 
   if [[ $command == 1 ]]
   then
      counter
   fi
   readCommand $command
   command=$?
done
```

The counter will stop if user presses `'p'` and go on if user presses `'g'`

Answer (score 1):

Simple script with file descriptor and simple input redirection, leaving no temporary files to cleanup. The waiting is done by using `read` parameter `-t`.

```
counter() {
        while ! read -t 0.05 -n1 _; do
                printf '\r\t%s' "$(date +%T.%N)"
        done
}

{
        IFS= read -p "Your name, Sir?"$'\n' -r name
        echo >&3
} 3> >(counter "$tmp")

echo "Sir $name, we exit"
```

Example output:

```
Your name, Sir?
    2:12:17.153951623l
Sir Kamil, we exit
```

Comment: This looks very promising -- sadly, does not work on BSD (OSX), which does not support decimal timeouts for `read`. (But I didn't specify OSX in the problem statement.)

Comment: Hm, do you have [timeout](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=timeout&sektion=1) with real numbers? I think you can `timeout 0.05 read -t -n1 _` ... and remember to check reutrn status.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a change in the code you refer.

```
...
while [ true ]; do
    if [ -z $(cat /tmp/pause) ]; then
        STOPWATCH=$(TZ=UTC datef $DATE_INPUT $DATE_FORMAT | ( [[ "$NANOS_SUPPORTED" ]] && sed 's/.\{7\}$//' || cat ) )
        printf "\r\e%s" $STOPWATCH
        sleep 0.03
    fi
done
```

So what you need to do now is a shell script that waits the "p" char from stdin and writes 1 > /tmp/pause or clean /tmp/pause to get he stopwatch paused or working.

something like:

```
while read char;
do 
   if [ $char == "p" ]; then
       if [ -z $(cat /tmp/pause) ];then
           echo 1 > /tmp/pause
       else
           echo > /tmp/pause
       fi
       char=0 
   fi
done < /dev/stdin
```